# How to open dialogue box onclick of cell in inline editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with inline editing. I want to open a 'dialogue box' on click of cell. In that dialogue box, i will search some value and the selected value to be populated in my jqgrid cell. Same has to be posted to the server. How can I achieve this. Please help me at the earliest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can post data to the server from the client without a page refresh using ajax.

Comment: It seems be exact duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25463214/315935). I asked you in the comment to your previous question for additional information about what you want to implement. You posted no answer. You wrote in the new question: "i will search some value and the selected value to be populated in my jqgrid cell". It still unclear what exactly you need. Moreover you repeat the usage of words ["inline editing"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) for something other as it be in jqGrid.

Comment: You should post more your code with your current attempts and describe more clear where you have implementation problems. You can include some examples (with at least one row of data) and to describe on the example which data exactly you want to get from the grid and post to the server. In any way you should try first to use `getCell`, `getRowData` and `getLocalRow` methods to get the required information (see my comment to your previous question).